# Confirming browser prefetching is causing deletes

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, google-chrome

I'm trying to test a theory that prefetching in browsers is causing unexplained deletes within my django app.

Here's my delete method in my views.py:

```
def delete(request, part_id=None):
    obj = epe.objects.get(id=part_id)
    obj.delete()
    logger.error('Someone deleted record: '+str(part_id))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('epe_home'))
```

And how I use the url in my template:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'epedelete' epe.id %}"><input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Delete" /></a></td>
```

You can see I'm logging when this method is activated, but I still have had unexplained deletes without any logs from the logger. Which makes me wonder if the unexplained deletes are caused by my method at all.

The only logs I have of the deletes are from MySQL logs like these:

```
6798 Connect
user@hostname on dbname
6798 Query
SET NAMES utf8
6798 Query
set autocommit=0
6798 Query
set autocommit=1
6798 Query
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
6798 Query
SELECT `Epe_epe`.`id`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_type`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_type2_id`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_date`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_ani`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_ani2_id`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_apn`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_apn2_id`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_weight`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug_type1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_dose1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_amount1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_route1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_time1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug_type2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_dose2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_amount2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_route2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_time2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug_type3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_dose3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_amount3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_route3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_time3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug_type4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_dose4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_amount4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_route4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_time4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug_type5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_dose5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_amount5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_route5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_time5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug_type6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_drug6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_dose6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_amount6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_route6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_time6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_iso_start`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_iso_end`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_o2_end`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start7`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_start8`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr7`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_hr8`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_7`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_spo2_8`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp7`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_temp8`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_7`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_etco2_8`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr1`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr2`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr3`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr4`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr5`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr6`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr7`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_rr8`, `Epe_epe`.`epe_comment` FROM `Epe_epe` WHERE `Epe_epe`.`id` = 1508
6798 Query
set autocommit=0
6798 Query
DELETE FROM `Epe_epe` WHERE `Epe_epe`.`id` IN (1508)
6798 Query
commit
6798 Query
set autocommit=1
6798 Quit
```

The `delete` method above is the only case where I allow deletes within my app. I understand that having a destructive action within a GET request can maybe cause the unexplained deletes I'm seeing, so I'm trying to figure out if that's the case here. Is there any other place it could come from?

I'm not sure this relevant but I'm still using the dev server that bundles with django. I allow multiple users on multiple machines to access my app to help with the debugging process.  Could not using a production level server in this case somehow cause unexplained deletes?

Comment: You've already noted that using GET for a destructive instruction is risky - might be better to fix that instead? Even if you do manage to pin this to prefetching, your current approach is still dangerous and vulnerable to things like denial-of-service and cross-site request forgery attacks.

Comment: There are various places that you haven't shown that could be causing this behavior. For example, your `epe` model has a `delete()` method which is being called whenever your view is run. It's also possible that you could be manipulating the id of the objects elsewhere in your code, or in your database. It could be helpul to see what the model for `epe` looks like. Is there any pattern to the IDs of the objects being deleted strangely? Do their IDs correspond to previous database entries that were deleted for example, or the highest ID (say)?

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom . GET requests are *supposed* to be non-destructive. This isn't a browser misbehaving, it's *your application* that is doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Can we see the django logs? You might not have configured django logging correctly.

Comment: @DashCountrol can you check my solution and tell if it worked or not?

Comment: @argo I've seen that article before, but it still puts me in a situation where hard deletes aren't being logged through my django app. They are only logged via MySQL logs. So I'm still stuck with only the assumption that it is via GET requests, rather than a method that proves it is.

Comment: @rbicheno the views are the only areas where I have a delete function. I have an `on_delete=models.PROTECT` in my model for ForeignKeys, but that is all. There is no apparent pattern as you specified. The MySQL logs show the deletes occurring when the user claimed to be inactive, which adds to the pre-fetching assumption that it occurred when the browser was idle.

Answer (score 0):

Django class based generic views allow object deletion [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) so if you are using them you get delete method for granted in every view even though you don't define (overload) it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have taken seems correct. However I have another approach to find out the deletes. You can write a custom manager for the django model and then override the `delete()`. Put a logger there, the added advantage to this approach is that if any other django app or any one else tries to delete a row from this model then your custom `delete()` would be used.

You can follow [this article](https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/soft-deletion-in-django-e4882581c340) about how to implement delete using manager or overwrite the delete function of the queryset.